# reusable ajax and javascript function in CSHTML(RAZOR)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im new in js and razor,part of my code should be repeated and this imposed more lines of code to my project,it could be nice if i can make it reusable,for example Ajax,where should i create a ajax to a specific URL to just call it when i need?in a separated razor file?in the following code,i have two click events and my ajax call and url is repeating,i want to get rid of this repeat:

```
function seriesClick(e) {
var _clicketBarChart = e.series.categoryField;

$.ajax({
           dataType: "json",
           type: "POST",
           url: "@Url.Action("faultstatistics","Dashbrd")",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: JSON.stringify({ "name": _clicketBarChart }),
               success: function (result) {
              faultstatChart(result);
               }
});


      function changeEvent(e) {             
      var _clicketCellGrid = e.categoryCell;


          $.ajax({
           dataType: "json",
           type: "POST",
           url: "@Url.Action("faultstatistics","Dashbrd")",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: JSON.stringify({"name": _clicketCellGrid }),
               success: function (result) {
           faultstatChart(result);
               }
});
      }
```

Comment: Just wrap it in a function that accepts the required data you need to post and add it to your sites js script.

Comment: It would help if you showed what elements are triggering those functions

Comment: @Wheels73 i think i cant write razor in js file like "@Url.Action",right?

Comment: @StephenMuecke those function the first one triggers when i click on chart bars,the second one triggers when i click on grid row

Comment: @mrslt - You can.... Unless i'm misunderstanding your question. You can also just put url: "/Controller/Action" as well.

Comment: The only thing that appears to change is the value associated with the `name` property, in which case you need on one function for the ajax - say `function getdata(value) { $.ajax({ ..... data: { name: value },` .... }); }` and just call that from your 2 functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create single method that can handle two situations, please refer to this example (based on your):

```
var ajaxHandler = function(targetName) {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("faultstatistics","Dashbrd")",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({"name": _clicketCellGrid }),
    success: function (result) {
      faultstatChart(result);
    }
  });
}

var seriesClick = function(e) {
  var targetName = e.series.categoryField;
  ajaxHandler(targetName);
}
var changeEvent = function(e) {
  var targetName = e.categoryCell;
  ajaxHandler(targetName);
}
```